# VBA data type error - bad syntax?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hopefully someone can help me out with this. I have written a query in Access 2003 that combines a linked table `"taxon_group_max_per_site"` and a cross tab query "Distinct Species by group_Crosstab".

From the table I have the field `"Taxonomic Group"` and `"Max"`, and from the cross tab the fields `"Total_Of_Species_S"`.

The table and the cross tab are linked and the query works fine until I add in some VBA to give each Taxonomic group a score based on `"Max"` and `"Total_Of_Species_S"`.

The code below brings up `"Error 13: type mismatch"`

```
Public Function Invert_Diversity_Score (Total_Of_Species_S As Integer) As Integer

    If Total_Of_Species_S < Round("[Max]*0.5", 0) Then
      Invert_Diversity_Score = 0
    Else
      If Total_Of_Species_S < Round("[Max] * 0.75", 0) Then
        Invert_Diversity_Score = 1
      Else
        If Total_Of_Species_S < Round("[Max] * 0.875", 0) Then
          Invert_Diversity_Score = 2
        Else
          Invert_Diversity_Score = 3
        End If
      End If
    End If

End Function
```

The debugger shows that `"[Max]*0.5"` and the other multiplications do not produce a number it says `"[Max] * 0.5"= "[Max] * 0.5"`, which I think is the source of the type mismatch. How do I get the field to multiple properly? It looks exactly like the format shown in the VBA help.

Answer (score 3):

The round function is expecting a number as parameter, not a string! Assuming (max) is a number, you can then calculate:

```
Round([Max] * 0.75, 0)
```

But

```
Round("[Max] * 0.75", 0)
```

Will definitely not return anything viable

Answer (score 2):

"[Max] * 0.875" is just a string, how is VBA supposed to know that you are referring to the column [Max] from one of your tables?

Shouldn't [Max] be passed into the function as a second integer parameter? Something like this:

```
Public Function Invert_Diversity_Score (Total_Of_Species_S As Integer, 
                        MaxVal as Integer) As Integer
```

We need the code that shows how you are calling the function to really sort this out ...

Comment: +1 for noticing that square brackets could indicate the data access operator in VBA.

Comment: Hi
thanks all for the comments.
I think codeulike summed up my question for me, "how is VBA supposed to know that you are referring to the column [Max] from one of your tables?" I have no idea. I'm teaching myself VBA through a combination of using other folks code and books. Not very successfully, I might add.
So, Max is a column and it contains an integer. How do I let VBA know?

Comment: Hi
I followed codeulike's suggestion (added Max as an integer parameter) and Philippe's (removed the square brackets and the quotations).
I didn't change the code to use Else if as I'm too lazy but will use it next time
Cheers for your help guys. It is very much appreciated.
Davva

Answer (score 1):

For one, you should use the `ElseIf` keyword, there is no need to stack the `If`s here.

Second - what is `"[Max]*0.5"` supposed to mean? To VB, it is a string, which unsurprisingly you can't multiply with an integer.

Assuming `Max` is some kind of global constant:

```
Public Function Invert_Diversity_Score(Total_Of_Species_S As Integer) As Integer

  If Total_Of_Species_S < Round(Max * 0.5, 0) Then
    Invert_Diversity_Score = 0
  ElseIf Total_Of_Species_S < Round(Max * 0.75, 0) Then
    Invert_Diversity_Score = 1
  ElseIf Total_Of_Species_S < Round(Max * 0.875, 0) Then
    Invert_Diversity_Score = 2
  Else
    Invert_Diversity_Score = 3
  End If

End Function
```

If it is not a constant, then you must pass it into the function as well:

```
Public Function Invert_Diversity_Score( _
  Total_Of_Species_S As Integer, _
  Max as Integer _
) As Integer
```